# Given an array of strings, write a recursive method that searches for a given string in O(n) and returns the index. LMK how to fix error

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
//this is the method to get the first string in the arraylist
public static Integer findFirstString(ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings, String stringToFind) {
        if (arrayOfStrings.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
        }

        if (arrayOfStrings.get(0).equals(stringToFind)) {
            return 0;
        }

        //int index = 0;
        //Error is line below this
        Integer resultArray = findFirstString(arrayOfStrings.get(index), stringToFind); 
        if (resultArray == -1) {
            return resultArray;
        }
        else {
            return resultArray + 1;
        }
    }
```

I need help fixing the get(index) part, I'm not sure if initializing it helps or if it is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In you code your method

```
findFirstString(ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings, ....
```

is expecting an ArrayList, but when you can it as

```
findFirstString(arrayOfStrings.get(index)...
```

the method

```
arrayOfStrings.get(index)
```

only returns one Object.

Consider change your method so that it passing in an `index` which should be used like (not tested)

```
public static Integer findFirstString(ArrayList<String> arrayOfStrings, String stringToFind, 
                                                                        int index) {

    if (arrayOfStrings.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
    }

    if (arrayOfStrings.get(index).equals(stringToFind)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return findFirstString(arrayOfStrings, stringToFind, index++); 

}
```

Comment: would you mind telling me how to print the result in the main method? I have System.out.println(findFirstString...) but then idk what to do because I keep recieving errors